# Connecting to MySQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connector

I have searched the internet trying to find solutions on using java and JDBC to connect to MySQL. Unfortunately I have found multiple answers and none that solved my problem.

I downloaded the JDBC from MySQL, and unzipped the file to find the .jar. I placed the .jar in my C:/Program Files (X86)/Java/JDK.../JRE/lib/ext folder. I set my environmental variable classpath (maybe CLASSPATH, ClassPath ??) to the following:

```
%CLASSPATH%;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\ext
```

I use the script I composed based on all the different solutions I have seen to get this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class MySql {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection Made");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection not made");
        }
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() {


        Connection con = null;  
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "java", "java");
            System.out.println("Connection Made");

            conn.close();

        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return con;
    }


 }
```

It compiles with javac MySql.java. Then when it runs (java MySql) I get com.mysql.jdbc. I have read that I don't need to register the driver, but when I remove Class.forName all I get is 'cannot find JDBC driver' error.

I can't narrow down my problem to either:
1). Classpath not setup correctly.
2). Improper java connection code.
3). Unable to locate MySQL server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit -

I placed the .jar file onto Desktop for testing purposes. Changed system  classpath variable:

```
%CLASSPATH%;.;C:\User\User\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
```

Then when I add the trace for the error statement I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<Unkown Source>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadclass (Unknown source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadclass(Unkown Source)
    etc.
    etc.
```

edit 2 - I have spent two days using [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database) as a resource and none of the instructions I have followed have solved my problem.

Comment: Could you do e.printStackTrace() in case of exception and paste full exception into your question? The message alone isn't helping too much.

Comment: Did you include the JDBC jar in your build path?

Comment: It's time to get out of the habit of throwing things into ".../jre/lib/ext" as apparently that option [will be removed in Java 9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

Do this

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

You will see that the exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at MySql.getConnection(MySql.java:24)
    at MySql.main(MySql.java:10)
```

Remove the Class.forName. You might get an access denied or some other error but it will solve the ClassNotFoundException. Here is the final edited version that should work:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySql {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection Made");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection not made");
        }
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;  
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "java", "java");
            System.out.println("Connection Made");
            conn.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return con;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Class.forName() is needed to ensure that the driver class is loaded by the classloader. I would not remove it.

Comment: @AndreasVogl - *"Class.forName() is needed ..."* - Not since JDBC 4 (circa Java 6).

Comment: I'm getting error java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila

Answer (score 1):

If you need Class.forName() you have to use correct class:

```
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

But with JDBC 4 that has become no longer needed.

Create full Exception stack traces and use the result to search here - most common errors have been solved here before.

NoSuitableDriverFound is a **very strong** indication your mysql-connector.jar (not the .zip....) is missing from your classpath when you run your code.

You could try like this:

Run `java -cp .;C:\User\User\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar MySql`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the path including the jar file name of the driver in your classpath. Like so:

```
%CLASSPATH%;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-xxx.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Java is version 6 or above you doesn't need `Class.formName(...)` code.
And for ensure that everything works, compile and execute your code in the follow way.
To compile:

```
java -cp PATH_TO_DRIVER; YOUR_CLASS.java
```

To execute:

```
java -cp PATH_TO_DRIVER; YOUR_CLASS
```

Change YOUR_CLASS to the name of your class and PATH_TO_DRIVER to the path where you download the MySQL driver.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You doesn't need to put the driver on this location, it can be anywhere on your system since you specify the location when you compile or run your code (or both). The way I suggested you can avoid change your classpath environment variable too.

Comment: You just try the suggestion to see if it works as way to narrow down where your problem could be. Maybe your class path configuration is wrong or maybe your code or maybe the jar that you put in that location is not the real mysql driver. The way a suggested is less error prone because you lower your dependency on external system configuration.

Comment: I'm getting a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila

Comment: You have the same code as @Jan?

Comment: Yes I removed the driver location statement. I copied and pasted from @Josh Chapelle

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourSCHEMAname,"login", "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
  }
}
```